# valid_json? check in ruby is not working

Tags: ruby, json

I am trying to check whether the response is valid JSON. I am making HTTParty or Restclient request to some urls and checking whether the responses returned are valid JSON?

I referred the link [here](https://gist.github.com/ascendbruce/7070951). This is not working.

My code:

```
 require 'json'

 def get_parsed_response(response)
   if not response.is_a? String or not response.valid_json?
     # code 
   end
 end
```

Error:

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/httparty-0.13.1/lib/httparty/response.rb:66:in `method_missing': undefined method `valid_json?' for #<HTTParty::Response:0x00000002497918> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: The link shows a definition for a function which you'd call as `valid_json?(response)`, if you put it into your code. Also, since you'll invariably try to parse the JSON after ascertaining that it is valid, you'd just be doing the same thing twice. Just parse your JSON and rescue from an error, forget about `valid_json?`.

Comment: Why not leverage the power of `unless` instead of old `if not`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be calling [`response.body`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/Response#body-instance_method).

`response` is an `HTTParty::Response` object. What you really want to be working with is the `String` object that represents the HTTP response body.

Answer (score 3):

More specifically than in my comment, I suggest you use something like this:

```
value = nil
begin
  value = JSON.parse(response)
  # do whatever you do when not error
rescue JSON::ParserError, TypeError => e
  puts "Not a string, or not a valid JSON"
  # do whatever you do when error
end
```